# What is difference between Features embedding and Image Features?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, embedding

I have to calculate the similarity between 2 images, and I was guided to use feature embeddings of images extracted by Auto-encoders rather than Features extracted by CNN.

Can I know what is exact difference why Feature embeddings & why it can be used to calculate similarity but not image features extracted by CNN?

I have a high-level idea of Image features, that it is a generated data by running a single Foward prop on a pre-trained network (N-1)th layer, not the prediction layer(softmax or sigmoid).

And I know word embedding that projecting a dimension of a given word into more convenient feature dimensional space.

But what is the intuition of embeddings in Image?

When to use one over another ?

Comment: who told you  image features extracted by CNN can't be used to compute similarity? There are many DL papers that do exactly this

Comment: Yeah I was a bit skeptical about that too, but I was wondering why would someone choose one over another?

Comment: @Saurabh were you able to find the answer to this question? Which one is better?